# How to install the correct graphical drivers?

Tags: drivers, graphics

Is there some general flowchart-like procedure or tutorial on how to troubleshoot **graphical driver problems with Ubuntu?**

I am in a situation where I have a PC which I do not know anything about, I made a fresh install of Ubuntu, opened Unity and the screen started to flicker, decomposed itself into small tiles and became completely unusable.

I would like to learn how to troubleshoot such a situation. That is something like a detailed explanation on how to:

1. Make sure the problem is the driver and not something else
2. Learn what hardware I am using
3. Based on this information, reinstall the correct driver

I also do not know much about the world of graphic hardware companies and graphic cards in general, so if such a knowledge is important, please could you add some directions to find the necessary information?

As suggested in the two answers, I ran:

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

and found out that I have an **Nvidia** hardware and **nouveau** driver. I tried googling the two and found [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia).

I turned off the GUI using `ctrl+alt+F2`, logged in and followed the instructions in the "Installation from console" section of the tutorial. I then rebooted and the problem seems to be solved.

Comment: The troubleshooting guide is here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/ to identify the video card run `lspci -nn | grep VGA` First step is to identify the hardware. From there support varies with open and closed source drivers, but the above guide should get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need root permissions. Some of the information are only accessible with the root account.

It varies from card to card but the most important logs are `dmesg` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (I don't know which logfile will use mir, `/var/log/mir/mir.0.log`?). Another tool that will be critical to identify the problem is `lspci` `lsmod` and `modinfo`:

```
sudo lspci -nnk | grep -A5 VGA
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV515 [Radeon X1300/X1550] [1002:7146]
    Subsystem: VISIONTEK Device [1545:2352]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

This will tell me what driver/module I'm using, with `modinfo` I could tell the details of the module, and `lsmod` will inform me if any other driver is loaded.

That is the basic that will allow you to search for more information and point where the problem might be.

Useful resources:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Debugging
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingCompiz
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Symptom
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingCompiz

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question: The symptoms you're describing can hardly be anything else then a driver failure(besides a hardware problem like overheating/underfeading).

Second: try to open a terminal Ctrl + Alt + T and type

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

this will show you your graphic cards inside your machine.

Third: well lets first await the results of the previous step then we can get into installations.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I am not with the PC now, I will be in a few hours and reply asap